# How do I get an Instagram permanent access token using REST API in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, instagram, access-token

I have offline access the instagram REST API,

But expire the instagram access token.

How do I get an Instagram permanent access token using REST API in PHP?

(or)

How do I get an Instagram access token without user login ?

Thanks Advance...!!!

Comment: What do you mean with having 'offline access the [...] API'?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I get an Instagram *permanent* access token using REST API in PHP?

From the [API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> Note that we do not include an expiry time. Our access_tokens have no explicit expiry, though your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access or we expire the token after some period of time.

So all Instagram access tokens are "permanent" until either the user or Instagram expires it.

#### How do I get an Instagram access token without user login ?

You shouldn't be able to, because that would mean a security breach. If I revoke the token I authorized you to have, you shouldn't be able to just get a new one without my approval.

Comment: As of today, **" tokens are unique to a user and should be stored securely. Access tokens may expire at any time in the future. "**  https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: As of today, seems it won't have any permanent token [Instagram API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#instagram-user-access-tokens)